# Meaning of phrase "rent full month"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "I only rent out full month" mean when said by a potential landlord?

At first I thought it means that the apartment can only be rented starting at the first day of a month, but now I think it might mean that it is only rented out for one month at a time. Is it a standard phrase in English or should I ask the person who said it to clarify?

Comment: You had better ask the landlord what is meant, but my guess is the apartment will not be rented out for less than a full month, i.e. not one day or one week.

Comment: I think it will mean closer to your first idea: you can only start on the first day of a month, and you can only finish on the last day of a month.  Even if you live there for a full year, when you decide to move out, if you tell him "I am leaving on the 12th", he will still require you to pay a full month's rent (paying for the 13th-31st even though you won't be using the place those days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would sugges you ask the person who said it, however its only logical to assume that he meant was the time frame of the rent, so you must rent for 1 full month (usually calendar month) and not less